# What algorithm does this use for face recognition?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, face-recognition

I am looking at codes for facial recognition but I need to know what algorithm is used.
It uses OpenCV and face_recognition. Is there any way to tell the algorithm used from this?

```
 # face recognition
    faces_cur_frame = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
    encodes_cur_frame = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, faces_cur_frame)
    # count = 0
    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodes_cur_frame, faces_cur_frame):
        match = face_recognition.compare_faces(encode_list_known, encodeFace, tolerance=0.50)
        face_dis = face_recognition.face_distance(encode_list_known, encodeFace)
        name = "unknown"
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_dis)
        # print("s",best_match_index)
        if match[best_match_index]:
            name = class_names[best_match_index].upper()
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y2 - 20), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        mark_attendance(name)

    return frame
```

Comment: What do you mean by "algorithm" here? It's using some package called "face_recognition" which is maybe https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.

Comment: Algorithms like Eigenfaces, CNN, HoG, DNN, HAAR cascade, etc.

Comment: No, it's not possible to tell what algorithm is used from the code you've included in the question. You have to find the package that it's using, and read the documentation or the code of that package.

Comment: ohh I see. Thank you so much!